# GridView navigation

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-8

This is part of the code of from the Windows 8 app of mine. 
Instead of using the grid template by VS 2013,I create my own grid template in the blank app. The following code allows me to navigate grid by grid to different pages in the app. Can I know is there any way that I can **navigate to other pages in the app** by using the **index of the GridView** and **use if-else statement to determine which page to navigate when the grid is selected**?

```
   private void grid1_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(pageA), sender as Grid);
    }

    private void grid2_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)        
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(pageB), sender as Grid);
    }

    private void grid3_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(pageC), sender as Grid);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a unique name to each grid and attach grid's tapped event to a single event handler

here's the XAML

```
            <Grid x:Name="Grid1" Tapped="Grid_Tapped">
                <!--Your Code Here-->
            </Grid>

            <Grid x:Name="Grid2" Tapped="Grid_Tapped">
                <!--Your Code Here-->
            </Grid>

            <Grid x:Name="Grid3" Tapped="Grid_Tapped">
                <!--Your Code Here-->
            </Grid>
```

and for the event you can just typecast the sender to the type Grid and get the name of the grid and based upon that execute the code you want to, like this

```
    private void Grid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((Grid)sender).Name == "Grid1")
        {
            //your code for grid1
        }
        else if (((Grid)sender).Name == "Grid2")
        {
            //your code for grid2
        }
        else if (((Grid)sender).Name == "Grid3")
        {
            //your code for grid3
        }
    }
```